# How to make the bins line up in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used ggplot2 to plot a histogram shown below. I set the width of the bin into 5 or 10. However, the first bin in the chart seems to be only half of the bin width. 5-2.5 and 10-5. What caused this problem and how can I solve it?

[image: Histogram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control how bins line up with the `center` and `boundary` parameters. In this case, you probably want `boundary = 0`

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100)*10)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, boundary = 0, color = "black", fill = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: it works! thank you!